# How can I disable javascript alert and access the webpage?

Tags: javascript

Few days ago I opened a webpage of my academics website, I wanted to download the webpage but it has a javascript alert box pop up so after that I wasn't able to access anything either on the browser or the webpage. Finally I had to close it, and after closing the alert box it also closes the webpage.

Is there any way I can download the webpage by disabling that alert box and accessing the webpage?

Sorry I cannot share much information and credentials so I am attaching the image below, I hope you got what I am asking.

Also can I remove the alert box by injecting some JavaScript in the url?

[image: Image for above scenerio]

Comment: You can disable javascript completely, but Chrome should give you the option to only disable alerts for the page after a couple of them show up.

Comment: This really isn't a security question but a web browser use question. Also, you should be contacting the site's support (or changing your print settings like it says).

Comment: sorry I was confused where to ask this question, anyway I have updated it.

Comment: this question might be better for http://superuser.com/ stackexchange

Comment: "can I remove the alert box by injecting some JS in the url?" I don't think so, but you can disable further alert boxes with something like: `javascript:window.alert=undefined`

Comment: even I chose the option in chrome to prevent further alert boxes but it is also coming again after reopening the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable javascript in your browser, then download the page. For mozilla firefox go there :
[mozilla docs](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/javascript-settings-for-interactive-web-pages?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript).